# Reparse Google Plus Button?

Tags: javascript, google-plus-one

I have a website where pages are loaded via AJAX so I reload the Facebook comments box and like button (`FB.XFBML.parse()`) each time a link is opened.  I was wondering if there is a similar way to reload the Google Plus button with JavaScript for a page.

Comment: Nevermind.  I think I got it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Google Plus button to show after inserting markup with ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495049/getting-google-plus-button-to-show-after-inserting-markup-with-ajax)

Answer (score 4):

Parsetags should be set to explicit.

See: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/

Then you can call `gapi.plusone.go();` to have the tags re-parsed.

Comment: I found my own solution but I appreciate the answer.  What I'm wondering is, through your method, how do you change the attributes properly?  I am grabbing the element directly and modifying its HTML.  Let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, Secretus is my other account so respond to this one however you choose.

Comment: What you should do is to remove the existing one from the DOM completely and then re-add it back into the DOM with the correct attributes, then call the gapi.plusone.go();